# fullPage.js loading issue caused by calling

Tags: jquery, slider, fullpage.js

I'd like to use fullPage.js ( by https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js ) inside a div in another directory of my site, but I don't understand where's the issue and How to solve. I've broken my mind over the net with any result :(

Test site: http://simonenicosia.com/fullPage/

I guess the problem is I'm calling an html to another dir ( /projects/timeline.html ) to load content and it doesn't activate:

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
        sectionsColor: ['#1bbc9b', '#4BBFC3', '#7BAABE', 'whitesmoke', '#ccddff'],
        scrollingSpeed: 1000
      });
```

Click on the following image to activate the script there:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not showing us enough code so we can only guess.
The problem is not in the initialization but on when you call the initialization.

If I click on the image (so the #fullpage div is added) and then in the JS console I add `$('#fullpage').fullpage()`  to initialize fullpage.js, it will work as expected.

So one thing is clear. The problem is when you initialize it.

Comment: You gave me a precious point and I've edited my code with the calling in another point of my div. Thank you!